# ¿Porque al ejecutar mi SP tarda demasiado el mostrar los resultados? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, rendimiento

Siempre he tenido la duda de que hay veces que las consultas o SP arrojan rapidisimo los resultados pero hay veces que no, por ejemplo tengo un sp el cual arroja hasta 400,000 registros y no me tarda más de 20-30 segundos y ahora que intente realizar el siguiente SP esté me tarda demasiado ya que hasta ahora al ejecutarlo por lo menos 20 minutos tarda, si bien al ejecutar estas vistas del otro servidor y al almacenar sus resultados en tablas temporales puede causar que tarde, adémas de los filtros agregados no se porque más se deba la lentitud, ¿Alguien me podria ayudar a mejorar el rendimiento de su ejecución? Soy un principiante en SQL si bien he investigado aún no conozco maneras de aumentar el rendieminto de ejecución. Gracias de antemano!

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TR_RepGeneralidadesDL
@UserID varchar(100),
@Report varchar(100),
@Setting varchar(100),
@dummy varchar(max) NULL
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @res varchar(max)= NULL                 
        DECLARE @t TABLE (resultado VARCHAR(MAX))

        DECLARE @Fechainicio date
        set @Fechainicio = '01-01-2019'
        DECLARE @Fechafin date
        set @Fechafin = GETDATE()
                    
        declare  @curso varchar(max) 
        set @curso = (select Val from tblMatrices where ID=730)
        declare  @Idmatriz varchar(max) 
        set @Idmatriz = (select id from tblMatrices where ID=730)

        /*  Tabla temporal para almacenar los resultados del SP [udpM12953_Reporte065]  */
        DECLARE @temp_065 table (
        paquete varchar(80) null,
        clave varchar(200) null,
        nombre_curso varchar(max) null,
        emp_clave int null,
        nombre varchar(250) null,
        fecha_examen date null,
        calif varchar(20) null,
        es_fecha_inicio varchar(150) null,
        comentario varchar(max) null,
        instructor varchar(150) null,
        nombre_instructor varchar(150) null,
        TipoCurso varchar(100) null
        )
        
        /*  Tabla temporal para almacenar los resultado de la lista de cursos   */
        DECLARE @udvM12953_CoursesList TABLE (
        cur_clave varchar(max),
        cur_nombre varchar(max),
        fecha_valido_desde date,
        duracion int,
        RevisionID int,
        RevisionName varchar(200),
        tipo_empleado varchar(50)
        )

        /*  GUARDAR DUMMY Y REEMPLAZAR  */      
            BEGIN                       
                INSERT INTO @t 
                exec spu_SetUserSetting @UserID, @Report, @Setting, @dummy          
                SELECT @res=resultado FROM @t

            /*  MATRIZ INDUSTRIAL   */
            IF @Idmatriz = '730'                
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @temp_065
                exec [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[dbo.Report_201873]
                @DateStart = @Fechainicio,--@dStart,
                @DateEnd = @Fechafin,--@dEnd,
                @cur_clave_str = @curso,
                @emp_clave_str = @dummy --emp_clave             

                /*  Lista de Cursos */
                INSERT INTO @udvM12953_CoursesList
                exec [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[dbo.CourseList]

                ;With cteGeneralidadesDL as(
                SELECT                  
                    h.workDayId,h.EmployeeName,h.JobPosition,h.Manager1,h.eMailSupervisor,h.Manager2,h.hireDate,h.OperationsManager
                    ,t.clave,t.nombre_curso,                    
                    MAX(t.fecha_examen) fecha_examen,
                    MAX(t.calif) calif,
                    c.fecha_valido_desde,                   
                    c.tipo_empleado
                    FROM TableHeadCount h 
                    LEFT JOIN @temp_065 t ON h.workDayId = t.emp_clave
                    LEFT JOIN @udvM12953_CoursesList c ON t.clave = c.cur_clave 
                    WHERE workDayId IN (SELECT value 
                        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dummy, ',')) 
                    AND tipo_empleado IS NULL
                    OR tipo_empleado = 'DL'
                    GROUP BY h.workDayId,h.EmployeeName,h.JobPosition,h.Manager1,h.eMailSupervisor,h.Manager2,h.hireDate,h.OperationsManager,
                    t.clave,t.nombre_curso,c.fecha_valido_desde,c.tipo_empleado
                    ), cteGeneralidadesDL_Two as (
                    select 
                    workDayId,EmployeeName,JobPosition,Manager1,eMailSupervisor,Manager2,hireDate,OperationsManager,
                    clave,nombre_curso,
                    case when(calif = 'C') 
                    then '100'
                    else calif
                    end as calif,
                    fecha_examen,fecha_valido_desde                 
                    from cteGeneralidadesDL
                    ), cteGeneralidadesDL_Three as (
                    Select
                    workDayId,EmployeeName,JobPosition,Manager1,eMailSupervisor,Manager2,hireDate,OperationsManager,
                    clave,nombre_curso,
                    case when(calif >= 80 and fecha_examen >= fecha_valido_desde)
                    then '1'
                    else NULL
                    end as calif,
                    fecha_examen,fecha_valido_desde
                    from cteGeneralidadesDL_Two
                    )
                    select * from cteGeneralidadesDL_Three                  

                END
            END
END
GO
```

Comment: Ya viste los planes de ejecución? Ya mediste el impacto de los diferentes llamados a los varios procedimientos almacenados? Hay mucho que investigar... No me quedó claro lo que preguntas. Cuál es exactamente tu pregunta? porque "mi procedimiento almacenado es lento" suena más a un tícket para desarrollo. Pero decir "Cómo puedo reducir los full table scans o los table reads en esta sentencia sql" es algo con lo que podemos trabajar.

Comment: @Arriel Lo siento, no he visto nada de lo que comentaste, como mencione soy un completo novato y no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre SQL para utilizar lo que me comentaste ya que ahora que investigue eso realmente no tengo mucha idea de como leerlo

Comment: tambien deberías de considerar si realmente necesitas ver la información desde 2019

Comment: Sí. Leer planes de ejecución es un arte en sí mismo. Anyway. Hay muchísimo que investigar y es probable que incluso los usuarios expertos en sql no puedan decirte exactamente qué hacer, pero sí pueden ofrecer un lugar dónde empezar. Suerte!

Comment: Hay cosas que se pueden ver y cosas que no. Tienes un par de procedimientos almacenados que no se pueden ver, pero que probablemente sean el problema. En especial porque hacen referencia a otro servidor. También es poco aconsejable usar variables tipo tabla y es mejor usar tablas temporales. De ahí en más es complicado saber que pueda causar los problemas sin conocer estructura de tablas e índices así como número de filas involucradas y planes de ejecución.

Comment: @LuisCazares gracias a que me mencionaste sobre mis variables tipo tabla que use decidi hacer el cambio a tabla temporal y me ayudo mucho, no se porque pero ya no me tarda demasiado, se tarda aprox 1.30 min regresar resultados de 200,000 registros. ¿En tú opinión esto es bueno?

Comment: Un minuto y medio para 200,000 filas me parece mucho, pero depende de lo que esté haciendo y la cantidad real de filas que procese. A final de cuentas, creo que para optimizarlo por completo necesitas una ayuda que va más allá del alcance de este sitio.

Comment: @LuisCazares  Bueno creo que teniendo en cuenta lo que mencionas sobre la cantidad real que procesa el SP sea la causa de que tarde, puesto que de los sp que inserto a mis tablas temporales desde el otro servidor son de 350,000 y 17,000 filas correspondientes, las cuales hago join con mi tabla principal que tiene aproximadamente 6,500 filas para despues solo mostrar aquellos que ingrese en la variable `dummy` de mi SP que al final regresa aprox 220,000 filas